# How to get a link href using selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

this is a link on a page im automating:

[image]

and this is when I inspect it's element:

[image]

I want to get only the

> /console/agent_invoices/2297294

which is the href...

How can I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getAttribute` method:

```
String hrefText = yourLinkElement.getAttribute("href");
```

If you also need to find your linkElement first, you need to provide more code.

Given you only have one link Element:

```
WebElement yourLinkElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName("a));
```

Or for example if you already identified the div-Element, that we see with the closing tag in your question you can do this:

```
WebElement yourLinkElement = divElement.findElement(By.tagName("a));
```

Answer (score 2):

First find element and get its attribute value in variable as explained below.

```
String linkText = webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href");
```